# Ofstream files not being made when argument file is in a different directory than current directory

Tags: c++, cmake, file-io, ofstream

To compile my program, I use a written cmake file like below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3 FATAL_ERROR)
project(GARFIELD_SIMULATIONS)

#---Find packages-------------------------------------------------------
find_package(Garfield REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

#---Build executables-----------------------------------------------------------
add_executable(test1 test1.C)
target_link_libraries(test1 PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX Garfield)

add_executable(test2 test2.C)
target_link_libraries(test2 Garfield)
```

This compiles my programs without any issues. However, I am having problems creating output files when I run my executables. Specifically, test1.C takes in a file as input argument and produces an output file by doing something like this:

```
string filename = argv[1];
ifstream input(filename, std::ios::in);
double x;
vector<double> xs;
while (input >> x) {
  xs.push_back(x);
}

ofstream output("output_of_"+filename, std::ios::out);
double y;
for (int i = 0; i < xs.size(); i++) {
  y = xs.at(i) + 1;
  output << y << "\t";
}
output.close();
```

Now, the issues arrive when I try to pass in an argument that is not in my current directory. For example, if I do something like this:

```
./test1 file1.txt
```

then I would get the output file. However, if I do something like:

```
./test1 /some/other/directory/file1.txt
```

I will not get any output file. I tried to search for the output by using find, but that returns nothing. I am still new to cmake, so I apologize if this is something obvious. I tried to use Google but nothing helpful has shown up yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your code actually looks like that, then `/some/other/directory/file1.txt` will translate to `output_of_/some/other/directory/file1.txt`, which is probably not what you want (and chances are that it actually fails since such address is not valid).

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes you are right! When I print the name of the output file, it says output_of/some/other/directory/file1.txt, but does this prevent the file to be made?

Comment: That would depend on what your `/some/other/directory/file1.txt` actually is. If it's full path - if I'm not mistaken - the result (`output_ofC:/...`) is not a valid filename

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes the input file is usually one or two directory above the current one, so my exact output name when I print it is output_of../inputs/file0.txt.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried that, but it does not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @KaneBilliot So... I googled and it seems that [a directory name cannot end with a dot](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/98348-cannot-rename-folder-dot.html). Thus, the output file name your code generates is actually not valid

Comment: @KaneBilliot you are not validating the output is open for writing, e.g. `if (!output.is_open()) { std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n"; return 1; }` Immediately after `ofstream output("output_of_"+filename, std::ios::out);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for clarifying. When I add in that line, the error message is returned. So, I think that the naming scheme I'm using is not allowed like IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes suggested

Comment: Is there a way for me to extract only the name of the file from the input argument?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes - I stand corrected, `filename` being a string is fine, I was stuck in initialization mode...

Comment: @KaneBilliot -- if I'm reading the tea-leaves correctly, when you add `/some/other/directory/file1.txt` you are trying to write to `output_of_/some/other/directory/file1.txt` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @KaneBilliot You can try to play with `std::string::find_last_of` to find the last ocurrence of '/', thus isolating the file itself, then `insert` the prefix at that position (just remember to failsafe it just in case no slashes are present)